# Please explain me this higher-order function javascript code

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

I'm studying higher order functions following the Eloquent JavaScript book.
I haven't been able to understand this code, why is "Boolean" passed as noisy first argument?

This is supposed to be function that changes other function, I just don't get how it works!

```
function noisy(f) {   
    return function(arg) {     
        console.log("calling with", arg);     
        var val = f(arg);     
        console.log("called with", arg, "- got", val);     
        return val;   }; 
} 
noisy(Boolean)(0); 
// → calling with 0 
// → called with 0 - got false
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`noisy` accepts any one-argument function as its argument. It returns a new function that calls that function, but displays messages before and after it calls it.

`Boolean` is just an example function that they used. It converts its argument to a boolean datatype.

Answer (score 0):

Boolean is a constructor function for the Boolean type. It could be any function.

Comment: It's not using `new`, it's just calling the `Boolean` function.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote this hastily. Take Barmar's answer instead. As far as I can see, the `noisy()` function is pretty useless. What I really wanted to point out is that `Boolean` is a constructor function.